# IPv6 Exit Policy Summary none defined

Tags: exit-relays, exit-policies, ipv6

Does that means that I'm an exit node if somebody connects to me through IPv6?

Answer (score 4):

nope. tor uses both IPv4 and IPv6 if one of them is not prohibited explicitly

UPDATE:

To reject IPv6 on all levels add this to your torrc:

- `ExitPolicy reject6 *:*` - it will disable *any* exit traffic for exit relay, see [ExitPolicy](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitPolicy) description
- `ClientUseIPv6 0` - it will prohibit Tor *client functionality* that serves your requests through Tor network to use IPv6. Docs are [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ClientUseIPv6)
- `PreferIPv6Automap Off` - it will prohibit in hosts auto-mapping(via AutomapHostsOnResolve) functionality to use IPv6, docs are [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#PreferIPv6Automap)
- In your [SocksPort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort) directives make sure **no IPv6 is explicitly enabled/preferred**, IPv4 is the default for SOCKS proxy Tor backend
- set `ClientPreferIPv6DirPort 0` and `ClientPreferIPv6ORPort 0` - it will disable an IPv6 preference for ORPort and DirPort connections
- `IPv6Exit 0` to disable using your exit as IPv6 one
- in ORPort flags add *IPv4Only*

and right - you use `reject` for IPv4 and `reject6` for IPv6

Comment: But if it is going to use IPv6 because there is no Exit Policy Summary defined, why do you say "nope" then? And how can I reject IPv6? I tried something with ExitPolicy reject6 *:* but I think I must use ExitPolicy reject *6:* instead, right?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @Binary Is your IPv6 broken, or are you trying to prevent some people from using Tor?

Comment: @MichaelHampton you're asking in such a provocative way, like if I owe you to run it...

Comment: @Binary You don't owe anybody to run Tor. But it seems strange to run it if you only want to block people from using it! So it's a little confusing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this case can be in many situations: ISP "easter eggs" with IPv6, unstable IPv6 when IPv4 is rock-solid... So - there's nothing to suspect

Comment: @MichaelHampton did you forgot about IPv4? It is still in use. Regarding to this manual https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TorDedicatedUser I deactivated it.